# Getting weird error on iOS react native project

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I’m using react native, I am trying to start my iOS app. It has React native firebase SDK. Please help. I have already initialized firebase in the app delegate

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**please verify the installation steps**

```
# Install & setup the app module
yarn add @react-native-firebase/app

# Install the messaging module
yarn add @react-native-firebase/messaging
#Update pods
pod install --repo-update   
#Insert this to Podfile
$FirebaseSDKVersion = '6.0.0'
#Install changes
pod install --repo-update   
# If you're developing your app using iOS, run this command
cd ios/ && pod install
```

https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Still having issues.

Answer (score 0):

seems your `firebase` module not installed correctly. following this link for install config your `firebase` : [Link](https://rnfirebase.io/)